# Vuex-map-fields updating multiple stores through modules

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm working Vuex modules to state my data.
I store the data in multiple modules to keep my code base nice and clean.

When using vuex-map-fields I have a situation where I'm using data from multiple modules.
There seems to be no method to do this or I am doing it wrong.

Below is my current code;
My component

```
<template>
    <div class="">
        <input type="text" v-model="no_panels"><br>
        <input type="text" v-model="firstName"><br>
        <router-link to="/step-2">Go to step 2</router-link>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { createHelpers } from 'vuex-map-fields';

const { mapFields } = createHelpers({
    getterType: [
        'getKitchenField',
        'getApplicantField',
    ],
    mutationType: 'updateKitchenField',
});

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapFields(['no_panels', 'firstName', 'lastName'])
    },
}
</script>
```

My store file

```
import kitchen from './kitchen';
import applicant from "./applicant";

export default {
    modules: {
        kitchen: kitchen,
        applicant: applicant
    },
    strict: false
 }
```

Applicant.js

```
import { createHelpers } from 'vuex-map-fields';

const { getApplicantField, updateApplicantField } = createHelpers({
    getterType: 'getApplicantField',
    mutationType: 'updateApplicantField',
});

export default {
    state: {
         firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    },
    getters: {
        getApplicantField
    },
    mutations: {
        updateApplicantField
    }
}
```

The code above results in the following error:

> Error in render: "TypeError: this.$store.getters[getterType] is not a function"

Comment: not too clear what your problem is here, have you tried using `namespaced: true` in your submodule declarations?

Comment: I'm sorry I'll modify the question with what the error is.

Comment: when using namespaced module you need to refer to it with the module name and a slash i.e. `'kitchen/getKitchenField'` and `'applicant/getApplicantField'`

Answer (score 10):

I'm the creator of vuex-map-fields, the Author asked [the same question on GitHub](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields/issues/18):

Instead of passing multiple getters to `createHelpers()`, you can destructure and rename the return value of `createHelpers()` and call it twice.

```
const { mapFields: mapKitchenFields } = createHelpers({
  getterType: 'getKitchenField',
  mutationType: 'updateKitchenField',
});
const { mapFields: mapApplicantFields } = createHelpers({
  getterType: 'getApplicantField',
  mutationType: 'updateApplicantField',
});

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapKitchenFields(['no_panels']),
    ...mapApplicantFields(['firstName', 'lastName']),
  },
}
```

If the desctructuring syntax is new to you, you can read more about it from Wes Bos: https://wesbos.com/destructuring-renaming/